# Update Or Remove Alacritty

Tags: uninstall

I built Alacritty by following the instructions from [Alacritty Github](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/master/INSTALL.md) and I don't know how to update it.

So, I thought if I install Alacritty with this code ↧, **It will be easy to update it.**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:aslatter/ppa
sudo apt install alacritty
```

Can anyone help me to **remove** it, or guide me on how to **update** it?

**Thank you**

Comment: Will `sudo apt purge alacritty` remove the software for you?  If you install something from GitHub, then "updating" it is probably similar to re-installing it using the installation instructions.  With an ppa repository, updating might be a bit easier, but it depends on whether the developer updates it regularly.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I didn't try `sudo apt purge alacritty` yet. the developer [PPA: antoine latter](https://launchpad.net/~aslatter/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) updates it regularly. I'm new so I don't know if it's safe to install it from him or it's safer to build it myself.

Comment: I'm glad someone else has already helped you!  To answer your question, the Alacritty Github is the source of the software.  Others with a PPA may want to re-package it to make it easier for others to install.  Or, it can become an official Ubuntu package.  The absolute "safest" is GitHub since that's the software source.  (If you don't trust the developer, then don't bother even using it.)  Everyone else is in the middle, even me if I told you, "yes!  You can trust them!".  How can you trust me to give you advice about a PPA?  Trust comes with time and the "feeling" is unrelated to software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, you should know the details of your installation procedure in order to be able to fully undo the installation. In as far as I see, everything from the compilation is under a `target/release/alacritty` somewhere. From there, you manually moved things out to `/usr/local/bin` and other places, as indicated under **Desktop Entry**. Just undo these actions.

- Remove `/usr/local/bin/alacritty`. Already from now on, the new version will be the one that you launch with the command `alacritty`
- Remove `/usr/share/pixmaps/Alacritty.svg`
- With respect to `Alacritty.desktop`, be carefull. It is most likely in `/usr/share/applications` when it is installed using `desktop-file-install`. It could have been overwritten by your PPA install, although some PPA's package the desktop file as `com.alacritty.Alacritty.desktop`. If the latter file exists in `/usr/share/applications`, then you can remove `Alacritty.desktop`. IF that file is not there, it may be elsewhere on your system. If needed, search where it is. You can then do a `sudo update-desktop-database` to update the system that that launcher is gone.
- Finally, remove the folder where the compiled files were placed if you did not already.

Some background: When you installed Alacritty from the PPA, the binary will be located in `/usr/bin`. However, the version that you have compiled manually is, if you followed all instructions, in `/usr/local/bin`. The latter folder comes earlier in the search path for applications (look at that path with the command `echo $PATH`). So despite installing the PPA version, the manually compiled version continues to be the one that is executed.

Comment: Thank you for your help. [target/release/alacritty] is on [~/alacritty/target/release/alacritty]. should I delete this folder [~/alacritty]? I don't know where the compiled files are. are they in the [~/alacritty] folder?
[Alacritty.desktop] is in [/usr/share/applications] like you said. I didn't install The PPA yet. If I want to update it by rebuilding it. will the new rebuild replace the old one? or I will get two versions of it. Thank you again.

Comment: I do not know more about the compilation process than what you pointed me to and followed. I guess also the compiled files are under your ~/alacritty folder. Rather than building yourself, you may prefer to se the PPA.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the updating `alacritty` from the source code would be more advisable at any point compared to installing from apt repos. I have suffered crashing at certain instances while using apt after upgrading my system.

To update it, I believe the best way to do it is, updating the repository to its latest.

```
git pull
```

Make sure whether you have the latest rust compiler.

```
rustup override set stable
rustup update stable
```

Then use to build it

```
cargo build --release
```

After building, I use symbolic links instead of copying the file, so when I update I don't need to copy file again and again. The system will use the same file at same location.

```
ln -s /Fullpath/to/alacritty/target/release/alacritty /directory/in/"$PATH"/alacritty
```